# Call to a member function from() on a non-object in my mail settings

Tags: codeigniter

I wrote this code to sent a mail in codeigniter

```
$this->mailconfig['mailtype']='text';
            $this->load->library('email', $this->mailconfig);
           $this->email->from('ajithm@qburst.com','Tony');
            $this->email->to($this->mail);
            $this->email->subject('PASSWORD');
            $this->email->message('Your password is:' . $password);
            $this->email->send();
```

But i got a error as PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function from() on a non-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->load->library('email');

$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';

$config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';

$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';

$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

$this->email->initialize($config);

$this->email->from('ajithm@qburst.com','Tony');
            $this->email->to($this->mail);
            $this->email->subject('PASSWORD');
            $this->email->message('Your password is:' . $password);
            $this->email->send();
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you can pass the config when loading the email library. In the [docs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html) this is a bit different:

```
$this->load->library('email');
$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
$config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

$this->email->initialize($config);
```